# What is the best way to specify a wildcard or regex in a "test" statement in configure.ac?

Tags: regex, testing, autoconf

I am writing a configure.ac script for gnu autotools. In my code I have some `if test` statements where I want to set flags based on the compiler name. My original test looked like this:

```
if test "x$NETCDF_FC" = xifort; then
```

but sometimes the compiler name is more complicated (e.g., `mpifort`, `mpiifort`, path prepended, etc...), and so I want to check if the string `ifort` is contained anywhere within the variable `$NETCDF_FC`.

As far as I can understand, to set up a comparison using a wildcard or regex, I cannot use `test` but instead need to use the double brackets `[[ ]]`. But when `configure.ac` is parsed by `autoconf` to create `configure`, square brackets are treated like quotes and so one level of them is stripped from the output. The only solution I could get to work is to use triple brackets in my configure.ac, like this:

```
if [[[ $NETCDF_FC =~ ifort ]]]; then
```

Am I doing this correctly? Would this be considered best practices for `configure.ac` or is there another way?

Comment: You do not need a regex  to check for a fixed string inside another. Use a wildcard search, `if [[[ $NETCDF_FC == *ifort* ]]]; then`. Regexps are generally more computationally expensive than "full text search".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` statement. Either directly as shell code:

```
case "$NETCDF_FC" in
    *ifort*)
        do_whatever
        ;;
    *)
        do_something_else
        ;;
esac
```

or as m4sh code:

```
AS_CASE([$NETCDF_FC],
        [*ifort*], [do_whatever],
        [do_something_else])
```

I would not want to rely on a shell capable of interpreting `[[ ]]` or `[[[ ]]]` being present at `configure` runtime (you need to escape those a bit with `[]` to have the double or triple brackets make it into configure).

If you need a character class within a case pattern (such as e.g. `*[a-z]ifort*`), I would advise you to check the generated `configure` file for the `case` statement patterns which actually end up being used until you have enough `[]` quotes added around the pattern in the source `configure.ac` file.

Note that the explicit `case` statements often contain `# (` shell comments at the end of the lines directly before the `)` patterns to avoid editors becoming confused about non-matching opening/closing parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. I knew my solution was kludgy and appreciate these best-practice examples.